# DESKTOP - UBUNTU 18.04 - 32 BIT - BOOTING & LOGGING IN PROBLEM

Tags: boot

I couldn't open my PC today as booting was stuck in midway and normal logging in page failed to appear. The outcome is given in the attached file viz. Shot 1.jpg. Thereafter I applied Ctrl+Alt+F4 to Login, but that also failed, outcome of which is attached hereunder viz. Ctrl+Alt+F4.jpg.[Shot 1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx1Oa.jpg) I need help to overcome the problem. 
[image: Ctrl+Alt+F4.jpg]

Comment: You are logged into your text terminal (on tty4). Why are you reporting it failed?  I see a *Failed to connect to* message, that resource is there (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts), but that error only implies a network issue and not a login failure.  Given you're logged in, you can look for issues in logs that may not be as visible on screen (eg. it looks like it's reporting the copper link was shut down, and you may see clues in your text terminal as to why).

Comment: @guiverc But I logged up to that extent and not further. I couldn't find my Desktop page, my other documents etc. However, it may be my ignorance. I would be privileged if you kindly explain further about what to do.

Comment: What;s the last thing you changed on your system before this happened?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I didn't change anything except updates offered by UBUNTU itself. Most probably it was an update of Firefox.